# Elementary freezes from time to time

Tags: release-hera, crash

I'm having troubles with Elementary OS, because it freezes several times a day. The whole system is suspending, cursor and everything doesn't work, but the music still still plays. Re-installing and update kernel doesn't help.

---

**OS:** Elementary OS 5.1 Hera

**Kernel:** 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu

---

**Huawei Matebook D14**

Ryzen 5 2500U

Vega 8

8 GB DDR4

256 GB SSD